# Oracle JDBC: Query returns 0 on Windows 10, but works perfectly on Windows 7

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm wrote some java code that generates invoices in the form of excel spreadsheets. It worked perfectly on the two computers I tested it on, but for some reason it did not work properly on a machine with Windows 10. After some testing, I narrowed the results to one single query, which is returning 0 instead of the appropriate value. I have tested this on 6 different computers and it works perfectly on the three ones running 7, yet the result of the query is 0 on all the computers running Windows 10. Note that all the other queries from the database work 100%, except for this specific one for some strange reason.

I am utterly unable to fathom why this would be the case and any input would be sincerely appreciated.

SQL Statement:

```
private static final String getCountSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM BATCHES  WHERE DEPARTMENT_ID = ? AND BATCH_DATE LIKE ?"
```

Code for the specific method:

```
private int getCount(int deptId) throws SQLException {
    statementCount = (OraclePreparedStatement) ocon.prepareStatement(getCountSQL);
    statementCount.setInt(1, deptId);       
    statementCount.setString(2, "%" + sDate + "%");

    ResultSet rCount = statementCount.executeQuery();

    int a = 0;
    while (rCount.next()) {
        a = rCount.getInt(1);
    }
    rCount.close();
    statementCount.close();
    return a;   
}
```

Just to be clear, I double checked both the parameters that are passed to the prepared statement and they are exactly what they should be. The result set is not empty, but instead contains 0 instead of whatever value it should.

Comment: What is `sDate`, how is it generated?

Comment: sDate contains a globally stored string generated by another method, taking the uppercase, first 3 letters of the month the users selects, followed by the year also selected by the user. For example : "DEC-16"

Comment: That sounds like a very suspicious way of handling dates, if `BATCH_DATE` is actually a date type, then you are depending on implicit date formatting by Oracle, which - IIRC - can depend on session settings, which might by locale dependent.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel The BATCH_DATE field in the database is a Timestamp(6) field which generally conforms to the following format: DD-MMM-YY HH.MM.SS AM/PM. The query is supposed to do a count of all the records for a specific department in a specific month and year.

Comment: Timestamps have no format, the conversion is done by Oracle when it needs a string, and afaik it always uses the session locale for that. You either want to switch to using `between` for your range (which has the added benefit that an index can be used), or explicitly specify the expected format using `to_char`.

Comment: ***Never*** pass date values as a String and **never** use `LIKE` on a DATE or TIMESTMAP column. Send a proper `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` instead. When passing the date value as a string you are affected by the evil implicit data type conversion and the format is determined by the _client_ sending the string, not the server.